# Determine a basis $B'$ of $\mathbb{ R}^3 $ composed of the union of $ Kerf $ basis and $ Imf $ basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

$f$ is an endomorphism of $ \mathbb{R}^3$ defined as:

$f(x,y,z) = (-x + y + z, - 6x + 4y + 2z, 3x - y + z) $

1.a Determine the matrix $A$ of $f$ related the basis of $ \mathbb{R}^3$.

1.b Show that $f^2 = 2f$

1.c Show that if $ v \in Imf $ then, $f(v) = 2v $

2. Show that $Kerf$ and $Imf$ are complementary in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and determine   a basis $B'$  of $\mathbb{ IR}^3 $ composed of the union of $ Kerf $ basis and $ Imf $ basis?

---

I have answered the questions above except the second part of question 2, I don't know how to determine the basis $B'$ as union of the basis of both $Imf$ and $Kerf$. Thank you.

Comment: I think one basis for the union is <1,0,0>,<0,1,0>,<0,0,1>. Since $ker f+ Im f = \mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @ZackNi Do I need to determine the basis for $Kerf$ and $ Im f $ and find the basis $B'$?

Comment: Umm... Tell me the basis for $ker f$ and $Im f$, which you have found.

Comment: I did not determine them because I was not asked to. I have $f(x,y,z) = 0 \implies (x,y,z) =(0,0,0)$. Could you please help me with that? Thank you.

Comment: "(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)" implies the kernel of f is the space merely containing (0,0,0). In other words, one basis for image of f can be $(-1,1,1),(6,4,2),(3,-1,1)$ derived from the coefficient of the function.

Comment: @ZackNi How can I write it as a union of the basis?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61495/discussion-between-zack-ni-and-jacob).